# Bootstrap Data table taking too much to load 400K rows

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I'm using data table to make my tables more user friendly (Sorting, pagination etc...), after a few months I got more than 400K of records and now the page takes almost 5 Minutes to fully load... I was thinking about using AJAX so I don't have to load all the records at once but how should I implement it?

HTML:

```
<div id="table_issue" style="display:none;">
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="dtBasicExample2">
                <thead class="table-active">
                <tr>
                    <th>DB ID</th>
                    <th>Jira ID</th>
                    <th>Status Code</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="issue : ${anonymizedIssuesPage}">
                    <td  class="border-top" headers="th1" th:text="${issue.id}"/>
                    <td  class="border-top" headers="th2" th:text="${issue.getUIString()}"/>
                    <td  class="border-top" headers="th3" th:text="${issue.getStatus().getStatusDescription()}"/>
                    <td  class="border-top" headers="th4" th:text="${issue.getFormattedStatustime()}"/>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see I'm using Thymleaf to get the data.

JS:

```
$('#dtBasicExample2 ').DataTable();
   $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
```

Comment: Use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side): _"There are times when reading data from the DOM is simply too slow or unwieldy, particularly when dealing with many thousands or millions of data rows..."_ Using server-side processing, you only ever send 1 page of results at a time to the browser (e.g. 10 records, or 100 or whatever 1 visible page of data is). The price you pay: You have to implement all your sorting/filtering/paging logic on the server.

Comment: There are lots of answers about DataTables server-side mode on Stack Overflow. Give it a try and research those answers if you get stuck.